# A collector’s problem with a rare item…

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

**First of all, I must say that this is not a problem that I have been asked to solve, but a personal thinking that has come to mind, and for which I can't find a satisfactory answer**.

Here it is:

A company markets toys (there are $N$ different types) that it conceals in chocolate eggs and it is assumed that each chocolate egg purchased contains one toy.

Now suppose there are $N-1$ types of toys that are evenly distributed in the eggs (there are as many marketed toys of one kind as there are toys of another kind). On the other hand, the $N^{th}$ type of toy is considered “rare”: it exists in eggs in limited numbers.

I assume I can model this by assuming that $T$ eggs are offered for sale and that:

- each toy of type $i$ (for $1 \leq{i} \leq{N-1}$) is present $x$
  times: taking an egg at random, the probability of finding a toy of
  type $i$, ($1 \leq{i} \leq{N-1}$) is: $\frac{x}{T}$
- the type $N$ toy    is present $y$ times (with $y<x$ by assumption):
  taking an egg at    random, the probability of finding a toy of this
  type is:    $\frac{y}{T}$
- we have: $(N-1)x+y=T$

The problem is to estimate how many eggs I have to buy to hope to complete the collection of $N$ toys, knowing that successive purchases will almost certainly lead to accumulating toys that I already have...

Since I didn't know how to start, I thought that, to better understand the problem, I should first solve the following question: I buy an egg; as each egg contains a toy, I already have $1$ element of my collection (of any type...); I buy a second egg; what is the probability that it is the same type as the one I already have?

So, I wrote:

- Event “second toy identical to first”: “$2=1$”

  Event “toy $1$ of type $i \,(1<=i<=N-1)$”: “$1=i$”

  Event “toy $2$ of type $i \,(1<=i<=N-1)$”: “$2=i$”

  Event “toy $1$ of type $N$”: “$1=N$”

  Event “toy $2$ of type $N$”: “$2=N$”
- Then:

$$P(2=1)=P(1=i \land 2=i)+ P(1=N \land 2=N)=P(1=i) \times P(2=i | 1=i) + P(1=N) \times P(2=N | 1=N) = \frac{x}{T} \frac{x-1}{T-1}+\frac{y}{T} \frac{y-1}{T-1}$$

- And:

$$P(2\neq1)=1-P(2=1)$$
If now I designate by $A_1$ the random variable giving the number of purchases that I must make to find a different toy from the one I already have, then it is possible that $A_1=1$ (if from the new purchase, I find right away a different toy…), or that $A_1=n$ (if during the first $n-1$ purchases, I find a toy identical to the one I already have, and if I only find a different toy during the $n^{th}$ purchase …).

So it seems to me that $A_1$ follows a geometric law with parameter $P(2\neq1)$:
$$P(A_1=n)= {P(2=1)}^{n-1} \times P(2\neq1)$$
With:
$$E(A_1)= \frac{1}{ P(2\neq1)}$$
To be honest, this way of doing things seems very complicated to me and I don't see how to continue... Did I make mistakes in my writings? Do I complicate things too much? Is there an easier way to solve this collector problem?
Any directions appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the [extensions and generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations) section of the Wikipedia plot summary for the coupon collector's problem give you what you want? (See in particular the last bullet.)

Comment: Incidentally, even if this had been homework, you've clearly put in enough effort for this question to be reasonably well received. Thanks!

Comment: Is the fact that there are a total of $T$ eggs your assumption or given? Because you state that you 'model' it this way; typically in problems like this- called coupon collector's problem- you just assume that the probability of drawing even without replacement for any type $i\leq n$ is fixed. This lends itself to an easy solution, but your 'modelling assumption' does make it reasonably more ugly since you'll have to use hypergeometric dist instead of just geometric dists.

Comment: If the rare ones are very rare it is easy.  By the time you get a rare one you will surely have all the others, so the waiting time for the set is the same as the waiting time for a rare one.  Very rare would be relative to the waiting time for the common ones, which is about $N \log N$.  If the rare one is several times $\log N$ rarer than the others you are in that regime.

Comment: `Vercingetorix`, yes, it was my own assumption; but you are right, I should try to use a constant probability of finding a `type i` object, say `p`, whatever `i` is between `1` and `N-1`, and a constant probability of finding a `type N` object, say `q`. I'll try to do this...